# Pass by const pointer vs. pass by value for built in types. Efficiency

Tags: c, pointers, reference, constants

I almost only find C++ posts and not C, when I try to find an answer for this.

For built in types as int, char etc. is there any performance difference between pass-by-value and by const pointers?

Is it still good programming practice to use the const keyword when passing-by-value?

```
int PassByValue(int value)
{
    return value / 2;
}

int ConstPointer(const int * value)
{
    return (*value) / 2;
}
```

Comment: The second is a lot more annoying to call (need `f(&x)` instead of `f(x)`, and introduce an extra local variable if you want to pass a constant value -- `f(5)` does not work).

Comment: Both of the problems that @delnan mentions are solved in c++ by using *references* a concept not present in c.

Comment: @dmckee: I am aware, but this is a C question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass by const pointer is never faster than by value as long as the value is less or equal the size of a pointer (`sizeof`). It also is more annoying and sometimes even wrong (stack variables).

Comment: The reason I suspected that const pointer might be slower for built in types is because of the fact that the size of the pointer might be bigger than, e.g. char (at least). Your answer is therefor marked as the accepted answer as you also included the why and not only yes/no.

Answer (score 1):

In general the pass by value should be faster. In fact the value might have been already in the  registers, in which case would not be necessary to access the cache. However if the function code is compiled together with the caller code, it is possible that the compiler will optimize anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Passing built-in types like int, char by pointer does not result in better performance results.

Using const keyword passing-by-value does not matter since original value won't be changed.